# How can I pass an existing controller to a state with specific args for injecting if I need to pass it like a string, not a function?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've implemented my **controller** like this:

```
angular
    .module(appSettings.appName)
    .controller('someCtrl', function (objectFromResolve) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.serviceName = objectFromResolve;
    })
```

And in another file I have the **state implementations**:

```
angular
    .module(appSettings.appName)
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(appSettings.stateNames.menu);

        $stateProvider.state(appSettings.stateNames.root, {
                abstract: true,
                resolve: {
                    objectFromResolve: function () {
                        return {};
                    }
                },
                templateUrl: './some_url.html'
            }
        );

        $stateProvider
            .state(appSettings.stateNames.menu, {
                url: '/menu',
                parent: appSettings.stateNames.root,
                templateUrl: './some_url2.html',
                controller: 'someCtrl(objectFromResolve)',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            });
    });
```

How can I pass the controller like 'someCtrl(objectFromResolve)' in order To invoke it not like a function, but a string and with args from the resolve object ???

Comment: you don't.  you use a resolve the elements the child state needs in the child state.

Comment: @Claies, so I have to implement controllers in the same file where the states are, after 'controller' statement only?

Comment: huh? no, you just need to use `resolve` in the state that needs the data.... using `resolve` has nothing at all to do with which files things are written in.....